# how to update 1 recycler view adapter from 2 view models?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have 2 view models observing 2 tables in room each emitting live data, they should update my recycler view when a value changes. My adapter is equipped to handle more than one model and view holder, but I'm not sure how to update the recycler views adapter with new data without overwriting the current data or duplicating any data any ideas?

So my adapter takes a list of Visitable (Visitable pattern)
I have 2 objects that implement this interface, the interface has a type so I can tell what view holder it wants and I update the recycler view using diff utils, it look like this

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {

private final List<Visitable> elements;
private final TypeFactory typeFactory;
private final ItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener;
private final Context context;
private String cardType;
private final String layoutIdentifier;
private static final String TAG = "Adptr-Card";
private String CARD_CLICK_UPDATE = "card_click_update";
private final String[] imageFilePathNames;
private RequestManager glide;


public CardAdapter(List<Visitable> elements, TypeFactory typeFactory, ItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener,
                   Context context,
                   String cardType, String layoutIdentifier, RequestManager glide) {
    this.glide = glide;
    this.elements = elements;
    this.typeFactory = typeFactory;
    this.onItemTouchListener = onItemTouchListener;
    this.context = context;
    this.cardType = cardType;
    this.layoutIdentifier = layoutIdentifier;
    this.imageFilePathNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_set_names);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View contactView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
    return typeFactory.createViewHolder(contactView, viewType, onItemTouchListener, glide, cardType);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(elements.get(position), position);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return elements.get(position).type(typeFactory);
}

public void setCardType(String cardType) {
    this.cardType = cardType;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return elements.size();
}

public List<Visitable> getList() {
    return elements;
}

public List<Sentence> getSentencesList() {
    ArrayList<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Visitable visitable : elements) {
        if (visitable.type(typeFactory) == CardViewHolder.LAYOUT) {
            sentences.add((Sentence) visitable);
        }
    }
    return sentences;
}

public Visitable getItem(int position) {
    if (position > 0 && position < elements.size()) {
        return elements.get(position);
    }
    return elements.get(0);
}


class CalculateDiffUtils extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DiffResult> {

    private final List<Visitable> oldCardList;
    private final List<Visitable> newCardList;

    CalculateDiffUtils(List<Visitable> oldCardList, List<Visitable> newCardList) {
        this.oldCardList = oldCardList;
        this.newCardList = newCardList;
    }

    @Override
    protected DiffUtil.DiffResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new VisitableDiffUtils(oldCardList, newCardList, typeFactory));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(diffResult);
        dispatchUpdates(diffResult, newCardList);

    }
}

private void dispatchUpdates(DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult, List<Visitable> newCardList) {
    this.elements.clear();
    this.elements.addAll(newCardList);
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}

public void refreshDiffUtilsList(List<Visitable> sentences) {
    new CalculateDiffUtils(elements, sentences).execute();
}



public void removeItem(int position) {
    elements.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}


public void addCard(Sentence sentence) {
    elements.add(getItemCount(), sentence);
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
}

public void addGroup(GroupsWithSentences sentence) {
    elements.add(getItemCount(), sentence);
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
}


public void updateCardClick(int position) {
    notifyItemChanged(position, CARD_CLICK_UPDATE);
}


public void refreshList(List<Visitable> newElements) {
    ArrayList<Visitable> elementArrayList = new ArrayList<>(newElements);
    elements.clear();
    elements.addAll(elementArrayList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

My 2 view models sit in a fragment, they observe some data from my Room database and are updated when changes happen, but this means I will only ever have the data from one of the view models, I guess I want a way to combine these view models maybe using some kind of mediator live data, here are my 2 view models (I've removed stuff for brevity, they are both initiated using factories)

**GROUP VIEW MODEL**

```
public class GroupViewModel extends ViewModel {

private final GroupRepository groupRepository;
private final LiveData<List<GroupsWithSentences>> groups;

public GroupViewModel(@NonNull Application application, String[] cardArgs) {
    groupRepository = new GroupRepository(application);
    groups = groupRepository.getGroupsByWordDescriptionAndWordType(cardArgs[0],cardArgs[1]);
}

public LiveData<List<GroupsWithSentences>> getGroups() {
    return groups;
}
}
```

**SENTENCE VIEW MODEL**

```
public class CardViewModel extends ViewModel {

private final SentenceRepository sentenceRepository;
private final LiveData<List<Sentence>> cards;
private static final String TAG = "view_model";

public CardViewModel(@NonNull Application application , int clicks){
    sentenceRepository = new SentenceRepository(application);
    search = new MutableLiveData<>();
    cardArgs = new MutableLiveData<>();
    cards = Transformations.switchMap(search, mySearch -> sentenceRepository.searchLiveCardListByWordTypeAndWordDescriptionAndSearchWord(getCardArgs()[0],getCardArgs()[1],mySearch));
}

public LiveData<List<Sentence>> getLiveCardList(){
    return cards;
}

}
```

**CALLING ADAPTER IN MY FRAGMENT**

```
private void setUpCardViewModelObserver(String[] args) {


        cardViewModel.getLiveCardList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), sentenceList -> {
            if (sentenceList != null) {
                ArrayList<Visitable> list = new ArrayList<>(sentenceList);
                cardAdapter.refreshDiffUtilsList(list);
                checkResults(list.size());
            }
        });


}

private void setUpGroupViewModelObserver() {
    groupViewModel.getGroups().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), groupsWithSentencesList -> {
        if (groupsWithSentencesList != null) {
            ArrayList<Visitable> list = new ArrayList<>(groupsWithSentencesList);
            cardAdapter.refreshDiffUtilsList(list);
            checkResults(groupsWithSentencesList.size());
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is welcome, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to use Mediator Live data, i set the new mediator live data to respond to changes to my existing live data objects and then mediate those changes so i now only have one stream of data so my card view model now looks like this

```
public CardViewModel(@NonNull Application application , int clicks, String[] cardArgs){
    sentenceRepository = new SentenceRepository(application);
    search = new MutableLiveData<>();
    cards = Transformations.switchMap(search, mySearch -> sentenceRepository.searchLiveCardListByWordTypeAndWordDescriptionAndSearchWord(cardArgs[0],cardArgs[1],mySearch));
    groupRepository = new GroupRepository(application);
    groups = groupRepository.getGroupsByWordDescriptionAndWordType(cardArgs[0],cardArgs[1]);
    sentencesAndGroups = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    sentencesAndGroups.addSource(cards, sentences -> {
        sentencesAndGroups.setValue(combineLatest(sentences, groups.getValue()));
    });

    sentencesAndGroups.addSource(groups, groupsWithSentences -> {
        sentencesAndGroups.setValue(combineLatest(cards.getValue(), groupsWithSentences));
    });

}
```

and my new combine latest method looks like this

```
private List<Visitable> combineLatest(List<Sentence> sentenceList, List<GroupsWithSentences> groupsWithSentences) {
    List<Visitable> visitableList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (sentenceList != null){
        visitableList.addAll(sentenceList);
    }
    if (groupsWithSentences != null){
        visitableList.addAll(groupsWithSentences);
    }
    return visitableList;
}
```